# Signing out from Google BigQuery in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Is there any way to sing out from Google BigQuery after once I logged in to it in Power BI?
I want to change accounts to which I logged in.

Comment: just find out by my own.

In order to do that you need open `Power BI Desktop` -> `File` ->  `Options and settings` -> `Data source settings` -> (click on data source that you want to change) `Edit permissions`

Comment: Please, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to `Home` -> `Get Data`. Select `Database` from the categories on the left, and you see `Google BigQuery`. When you're signed in, you see the following window indicated you've been authenticated. Moreover you have `Sign in as different user` option, which enables you to change the account. For more information, please refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-connect-bigquery).

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.

Comment: my Power BI version doesn't have such option when I directly go to `Get data`